# ace editor with tab-panel

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Hi i am trying to use ace-editor with tab-panel.  i can use separate ace editor for each editor-tabs. But if i didn't misunderstood, it is recommended to use one ace editor and create edit sessions for each tab.

My question is ;
I initiate ace editor like

```
var editor = ace.edit('someId');
```

so this initiates only one page by injecting ace containers on the element with id '#someId' 
so how can i initiate a session in another tab without duplicating the ace.edit(''). My confusion is i only have one element with id 'someId' and
i need two of them tom be shown in separate tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Ace can use id of an element or the element itself.
http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=ace

You can use some class or other selector of tab
in jQuery it would be sth like

```js
var editors = []; //let's have an array
$('some tab selector').each(function(index){
    editors[index] = ace.edit(this);
});
```

Or add some id's to each tab.
Important id must be unique for page!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i am doing right now is quite similar even almost same with your method. But i wonder that, for example. If i change editor theme i have to do that in each tab right? Because every tab has its own ace.edit('id') initialization.